# Trying to query GL_MAX_LIGHTS

Tags: opengl, lighting

I am trying to query how many lights are supported on my system, to test the glGet* functions.

As I understand it, 8 is the minimum, and I shouldn't really be using lots of lights anyway because of the required computation time. See this [thread](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/3d-graphics/229815/230625/re-opengl-max-light-limit/).

So far I have tried this:

```
GLint maxlights;
glGetIntergerv(GL_MAX_LIGHTS, &maxlights);
std::cout << "MAX_LIGHTS=" << (int)maxlights << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
MAX_LIGHTS=0
```

Can anyone explain why this is so? Since I have a sphere drawn, using lighting (from the OpenGL Redbook, Version 2.1, page 194) I know lights are enabled and working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably didn't initialize your OpenGL context right, see [here](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,5213).

**btw**
You shouldn't use the Hardware TnL functionality anymore because it is outdated.

Comment: Okay yeah, perfect, I didn't create an OpenGL context first. Thanks. (Upvote)